# Array de Controles en Vista de Diseño

Tags: java, netbeans

Como puedo generar una array de jTextField desde la vista de diseño, uso NetBeans he encontrado algunas soluciones pero recomiendan crear e insertar los controles programaticamente dentro de un jPanel, pero tengo problemas con esa propuesta ya que el diseño no queda conforme lo pide la interfaz gráfica propuesta en el diseño.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de a que te refieres con array de jTextField pero puedes hacer que dichos jTextField esten invisibles con setVisible(false) y luego mostrarlos cuando los necesites con setVisible(True).

```
jTextField1.setVisible(false);
jTextField2.setVisible(false);
jTextField3.setVisible(false);
```

y luego cuando hagas una accion especifica como presionar un boton pasen a ser visibles

```
jTextField1.setVisible(true);
jTextField2.setVisible(true);
jTextField3.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta SrMota, pero a lo que me refiero es a lo siguiente, tengo un formulario con varios jtextfield nombrados de forma serializada de 1 hasta n, y cuando cargo el formulario necesito llenarlos con los datos de un ciclo pero no logro como hacer que dentro de dicho ciclo agarre el nombre de cada n jtextfield para asignarle su dato.